# How to call the setCallback function with a callback function

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, javascript-remoting, javascript-controller

I am new to Lightning and am going through the Lightning Components Basics module.

In the *expensesHelper.js* file would like to find out if it's possible to move the callback function definition inside the *setCallback* function's input parameters to its own function and pass this function's name in the arguments instead.

Instead of this:

```
({ 
    createExpense: function(component, expense) {
        var action = component.get("c.saveExpense");
        action.setParams({
            "expense": expense
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var expenses = component.get("v.expenses");
                expenses.push(response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.expenses", expenses);
            }
        })
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },


})
```

I would like to move the callback function defintion out into its own function like this:

```
 ({ 
     createExpense: function(component, expense) {
         var action = component.get("c.saveExpense");
         action.setParams({
            "expense": expense
        });
         action.setCallback(this, this.cbackfunction);
         $A.enqueueAction(action);
     },


    cbackfunction: function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var expenses = component.get("v.expenses");
                expenses.push(response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.expenses", expenses);
            }
        }

})
```

With the code above I am getting the run-time error: "**Error in $A.getCallback() [component is not defined]
   Callback failed: apex://ExpensesController/ACTION$saveExpense
   Failing descriptor: {c:expenses}"**

I added a console log to make sure that "this.cbackfunction" exists and it does:

```
console.log("this.cbackfunction: " + this.cbackFunction);
this.cbackfunction: function (response) {
   var state = response.getState();
   var expenses = component.get("v.expenses");
   expenses.push(response.getReturnValue()); 
   component.set("v.expenses", expenses);
}
```

So, the *cbackfunction* function *is* visible from within the *createExpense* function.

Any ideas on how to call setCallback with a callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the body into another method, but you need to put a method inside the callback to call the other method to preserve the parameter:

```
({ 
     createExpense: function(component, expense) {
         var action = component.get("c.saveExpense");
         action.setParams({
            "expense": expense
        });
         action.setCallback(this, 
             response => this.cbackfunction(component, response));
         $A.enqueueAction(action);
     },
    cbackfunction: function(component, response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var expenses = component.get("v.expenses");
                expenses.push(response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.expenses", expenses);
            }
        }
})
```

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox, that worked. Could you please explain why my code didn't work and yours did? I am new to lightning and don't know much about javascript either. I come from a C, C# background. The "==>" syntax reminds me of pointers to struct members in C.

Comment: @user54373 `x => y` is basically `function(x) { return y; }` shorthand. You're creating a closure that can pass the component reference to the next function call. In your original code, component was out of scope and could not be referenced. You might want to read more about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), as they're incredibly useful. Notably, arrow functions preserve "this", which is also needed to make sure you can call the function using `this`.